# Computed fields in wave analytics not returning proper value

Tags: einstein-analytics

i have a computed field in my dataflow where i am adding three already computed fields when all the 3 fields contains any value other than 0. This is how i have written the logic

```
case when 'fieldA' !=0 && 'fieldB' !=0 && 'fieldC' !=0
then 'fieldA'+'fieldB'+'fieldC' else o end
```

Eventhough all the 3 fields contains some value other than 0, i am getting resultant value as 0 instead of sum of the values. what could be the reason. Am i missing anything in logic

Answer (score 0):

are you calculating the field1,field2,field3 in the same node where you are calculating the sum ?

if so then please calculate the field1,field2,field3 first and then calculate the sum in next compute node.

since the first 3 fields were not created and you were trying to add them up it was returning 0 everywhere.